# NPE while doing nextElement on an LDAP searchResult

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, jndi

I've an error inside the jre, while doing answer.nextElement()

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:111)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_31]    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.nextAux(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:245)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_31]    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.nextImpl(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:236)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_31]    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.next(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:184)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_31]    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.nextElement(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:88)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_31]

Here is my code:

```
        LdapContext ctx = ...;
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(...);

        if (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
            ...
        }

        while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
                String grpName = answer.nextElement().getAttributes().get("xxx").get().toString();
        ...
        }
```

I have no clue to know where to investigate.

Best,

Comment: Could you tell us which line is number 111? Is this code from LdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch?

Comment: How many node do you have? Because of this: http://rundeck.lighthouseapp.com/projects/59277/tickets/167-comsunjndildapldapnamingenumerationgetnextbatch

Comment: to investigate, start by breaking up the long line into several statements. That will help you figure out which part of the expression is null. Just a guess, but I would think that you reach a node that does not have the "xxx" attribute...

Comment: @Olivier Liechti, the NPE is not in my code but in the LdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch so the statement is in this expression: answer.nextElement().

Comment: @Valentin Ruano. This is not the code of LdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch but my own code. Error is thrown when doing: answer.nextElement()

Comment: @RoD In theory that would be then a bug in the Ldap framework as it should never return a NPE at this point; perhaps a IllegalStateException or some other runtime indicating a problem in a external resource (e.g. file) but not a NPE. Even if that is a bug from their part, this could be in turn be caused by a bug from your part as to how you initialize the object you are using, but not necessarily the case. I suggest that you look into the source code of that class for the very same vesion you are using and trace down the cause of the NPE, for example using a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. The problem I was having was that I defined the **maxResults** control in the LDAP search.

While iterating the **NamingEnumerator** and executing the **hasMore** method when the maxResults limits was reached, the exception **SizeLimitExceededException** was raised (this is expected).

The problem was that if after the exception was raised, you execute the **hasMore** method again over the **NamingEnumerator**, instead of returning false (as expected because the maxResults execption was already raised) it returns TRUE, and the following call to **nextElement** fails with the **NullPointerException** you are getting.